# httpurlconnection local ip address

Tags: android, eclipse, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect my android device to my sql database using my local ip address of my computer but nothing happens. I got errors.

> Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for BufferedReader [in BufferedReader.class [in java.io [in E:\Installer\Application\Eclipse\sdk\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\an‌​droid.jar]]]
>
> from my LogCat
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, String>{

    String json_url = "http://192.168.1.106/sample/sample.php";
    HttpURLConnection httpsURLConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            InputStream inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpsURLConnection.disconnect();

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the errors to your post. In this post you missed a `}`. I hope that it exists in your code.

Comment: Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for BufferedReader [in BufferedReader.class [in java.io [in E:\Installer\Application\Eclipse\sdk\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\android.jar]]]

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() - from my log cat

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line -

```
httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

You should make it -

```
httpsURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

There's an extra s after Http. You are casting it to the wrong class.

Comment: And also a renaming: `httpsURLConnection` to `httpURLConnection` would be less confusing.

Comment: i didnt notice that haha

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpURLConnection in place of HttpsURLConnection if you are using 'http' to talk to your local server. while 'HttpsURLConnection' is inherited from 'HttpURLConnection', it wont give you error when you are casting it wrongly but it might be giving you error when you are actually making connection over http.